# error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of 'std::greater<_Ty>'

Tags: priority-queue

```
priority_queue<Job, greater<Job>> wait_queue;
```

Went to compile my assignment and fixed all errors except the ones regarding this line of code..

Comment: never mind, this error was fixed with "priority_queue<Job, vector<Job>, greater<Job>> wait_queue; However, a new error has arisen, and I will post it if I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second template argument of `std::priority_queue` is the adapted container, not compare functor. You should use this instead:

```
std::priority_queue<Job, std::vector<Job>, std::greater<Job>>
```

Also, stop using `using namespace std;`.